# How to access a Visual Studio DTE Addin assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reflection, envdte

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. Create an executable that loads the Visual Studio DTE
2. Access methods of an Addin that is loaded

Here is my code, as followed loosely from [this blog](http://blogs.msmvps.com/carlosq/2007/10/11/frustrations-with-command-line-add-ins-for-visual-studio/).

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte;
    object obj = null;
    System.Type t = null;

    MessageFilter.Register();
    // Get the ProgID for DTE 10.0.
    t = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0", true);
    obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t, true);

    var addin = GetAddInByProgID(dte, "MyAddin");
    if (addin != null)
    {
        addin.Connected = true;
        var connectObj = addin.Object;
        var conObjType = connectObj.GetType();
        var methods = conObjType.GetMethods();  // mscorlib methods
        var asm = conObjType.Assembly;  //  is mscorlib
     }
     ...
}
```

The problem I'm running into is I can't get access to the Addin's assembly.  It appears that `conObjType`'s assembly is mscorlib - but I want access to Myaddin.dll.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any 3rd party add-in may not expose any method at all other than those required to implement the add-in interface (OnConnection, etc.). Its methods can be internal (not public) or even can be obfuscated.

If it is your add-in, a better approach would be that the add-in provides commands to perform actions, and given your external DTE instance, you can call DTE.ExecuteCommand("MyAddIn.MyCommand").